# About hashing and Polynomials

Tags: encryption, hash

I need your advice about hashing and Polynomials.
I am not a programmer so I am not familiar with complex technical terms!

I am currently creating an app that

1. shortens large blocks of text.
2. have the ability to return back to the original text

My first thought was to apply encryption/decryption using a public and a private key. But since the length of the encrypted text depends on the length of the plain text, I rejected that idea because my purpose is to shorten the large blocks of text. By the way, I am not interested for the security of the encryption/decryption (or hashing). My only purpose is to shorten the text.

From the other hand, I always liked CRC hashing algorithms as the hashed text is shorter than the plain.

As it is known hashes cannot be reversed to plain text (one way hash).

However, I came across the following web site which offers online CRC encryption.
https://www.lddgo.net/en/encrypt/crc

As you will notice, the site refers to a "Polynomial Formula". As far as I understand, this is the mathematical process for producing the final hash of a text.

My question is....
Since we know the Polynomial Formula, it is possible to apply the reverse mathematical process to find the plain text from the hash?
Again, I am not interest about the security of the plain text.

Thank you

Comment: You don't want hashing you want compression. Depending on your input, a simple yet effective compression method may be Huffman encoding

Comment: Thank you for the information derpirscher!

Comment: Don't know why you would use something like Huffman encoding if inflate / deflate should be available for about any language. But yes, compression it is. Modern crypto normally doesn't include compression, at best the ciphertext size is the same as the plaintext size (format preserving encryption, disk encryption etc.) but usually it expands compared to the plaintext size (for asymmetric encryption, IV and authentication tag for symmetric encryption & protocol overhead etc.). The "compression" used for cryptographic hashes is one way, and therefore useless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Maarten Bodewes :-)